# What is the work done in pushing an object up a slope of mass $m$ to a height $h$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, potential-energy

What would be the work done  when an object is pushed up a slope, My  teacher recently said that work done on the object would be greater than PE, can someone explain it to me if this is right or wrong and if so how can one calculate the work done

Answer (score 3):

The work done on the object is greater than the PE *if* there is something other than gravity that opposes the object being pushed. The two typical examples would be friction and air resistance.

If you can neglect both of them then the work done on the object should be equal to the PE.

Comment: Even if you negect both of them, still the work done by the pushing force does not have to be equal to the change in PE. It can have any value you want. It depends on how much you accelerate the body up the slope.

Answer (score 1):

What is equal to the change in PE is always the work done by gravity (with opposite sign). The work done by Any other force, like the one pushing up the body up the incline, has nothing to do with the PE, in principle. It may happen to be equal to the change in PE if the pushing force is so adjusted that the final KE is zero. And of course, if there is no friction. So the work done by this force depends on the problem. The work done by gravity is equal to the change of PE (with opposite sign) by definition.